# Graphing and arch length of a cycloid on Mathematica

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

Graph the cycloid $x=t- \sin t$, $y=1- \cos t$ and find the arc length of one arch of the cycloid.

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[x,y,t];
y[t_] := 1 - Cos[t];
x[t_] := t - Sin[t];
ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 6 Pi}, Ticks -> {Range[0, 6 Pi, Pi], Automatic}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 Solve[y[t] == 0 && 0 <= t <= 2 Pi, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 arcLength =  Integrate[ Sqrt[D[x[t], t]^2 + D[y[t], t]^2], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]

 (* 8 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ParametricPlot[{t - Sin[t], 1 - Cos[t]}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`ParametricRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricRegion.html):

```
pr = ParametricRegion[{t - Sin[t], 1 - Cos[t]}, {{t, 0, 2 π}}]

Region @ pr
```

[image]

You can use [`RegionMeasure`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionMeasure.html) or [`ArcLength`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcLength.html) to get the length of the arc:

```
{RegionMeasure @ pr, ArcLength @ pr}
```

> ```
> {8, 8}
> ```